# Try to fetch custom object data from database using spring data jpa from multiple table

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to get data from multiple table.

```
public class Student{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<Course> course;
}

public class Course{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private int studentId;
}
```

I want to fetch data from student and course table using spring data jpa and map to student object.
How can I do that in efficient way?

Comment: Here's a basic Spring JPA tutorial which should come in handy. If you've got more specific questions, update the question. https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Answer (score 0):

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Student{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="studentId",cascade=CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.Eager) 
    private Set<Course> course;
}
```

1. You May Use Set Instead of List.
2. Always Use Mapped By in OneToMany Side, If you use it manyToOne side it will create an
   extra table.
3. You can use  Fetch Type eager or lazy. By default, it is lazy with You have
   to use @transactional of Lazy.

> ```
>  @Data
>     @NoArgsConstructor
>     public class Course{
>         @Id
>         @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
>         private int id;
>         private String name;
>         @ManyToOne
>         @JoinColumn(name="studentId") 
>         private int studentId;
>     }
> ```

Hope this Answer Solve your query Happy Coding!.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the starting point might be wrong. I assume that a student can choose multiple courses and a course can be chosen by multiple students. So it is actually a `@ManyToMany` relationship but not `@ManyToOne` or `@OneToMany`.

You will definitely need a joint table to map their primary keys from two tables into the joint table.

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Student {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(
            name = "courses",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "student_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "course_id"))
    private Set<Course> courses;
}
```

```java
@Entity
@Data
public class Course {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @JsonIgnore
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Student> students;
}
```

Note all the modifications I have here.

1. For the data persisted into database, `Long` is a better choice than `int`. Similarly, e.g., use `Boolean` instead of `boolean`.
2. Think the `Student` as the side managing the many-to-many relationship, and `Course` as the target side. On the target side, use `@JsonIgnore` and `@ToString.Exclude` annotations to avoid an infinite recursion, StackOverflow or OOM.

```java
    @JsonIgnore
    @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
    @ToString.Exclude
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses",fetch = FetchType.EAGER,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
```

3. Use `Set` instead of `List` if a student is not supposed to select the exact same course. It ensures that one can still select `2017 fall Maths` and `2018 fall Maths`, while one cannot select `2017 fall Maths` twice.